# jquery validate field with name in multidimensional array with depend condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to validate input field if corresponding checkbox is checked :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="license_id_1" name="UserLicense[license_id][]" class="licence_value_checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="license_id_2" name="UserLicense[license_id][]" class="licence_value_checkbox" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" id="license_id_3" name="UserLicense[license_id][]" class="licence_value_checkbox" value="3">

<input type="text" name="data[UserLicense][licence_no][]" value="" class="licence_no" data-key="1">
<input type="text" name="data[UserLicense][licence_no][]" value="" class="licence_no" data-key="2">
<input type="text" name="data[UserLicense][licence_no][]" value="" class="licence_no" data-key="3">

<input type="text" name="data[UserLicense][expiry_date][]" value="" class="expiry_date" data-key="1">
<input type="text" name="data[UserLicense][expiry_date][]" value="" class="expiry_date" data-key="2">
<input type="text" name="data[UserLicense][expiry_date][]" value="" class="expiry_date" data-key="3">
```

Here i want to validate `data[UserLicense][licence_no][]` &  `data[UserLicense][expiry_date][]`  if checkbox is checked ( `data-key of text = value of checkbox`)

Textboxes and checkboxes can be multiple and i am using jquery validate

Comment: What does your jQuery Validate call look like now?  You should put that in your question.  Also, check out the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots)), which probably answers your question.

Comment: if i use validation for data[UserLicense][licence_no][]  or data[UserLicense][expiry_date][] then it validate first field only

Comment: Ah, you can't have 3 text boxes with the same name....

Comment: Thanks @Ryley , I resolved the issue by adding  index in each array like data[UserLicense][licence_no][1] , data[UserLicense][licence_no][2] and using each for class name